# For Loop All Products Regardless of Page Number

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I wrote a code for one of our Shopify store and it is not working the way I want. I request your support for this.

This is a check for every item on our collections page. I get the tag that contains the base_sku name of the product and I look for the products with this tag in all products.
Then I pull the tags containing color from the products with the same base_sku and link them under the main product.
I'm using pagination here and I know I can pull up to 1000 items. What I need is to be able to loop the pagination as many times as I want per product, regardless of the page number.
Because in this way, it only checks for the first 1000 products on the first page of the collection, and when I switch to the second page, it checks the number of remaining products.

Here I have to proceed with the tags because although the products seem to be variants here, all the ones I show are separate products.
https://gyazo.com/bc139013bdb7d9ad249ca907bf4b83a1

This is an issue that I have been dealing with for a long time but could not resolve, I would be very happy if you could support me.

Best regards,
Berk

```html
<div id="prod-var" class="prod-variants">
          {% for tag in product_card_product.tags %}
            {% if tag contains "BASE SKU" %}
              {% assign base_url = tag | split: "_" | last %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if tag contains "COLOUR" %}
              {% assign first_colour = tag | split: "_" | last %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if tag contains "SIZE" %}
              {% assign first_size = tag | split: "_" | last %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          <div class="variant-all-div">
              {% paginate collections.all.products by 1000 %}
                {% for product in collections.all.products %}
                  {% for tag in product.tags %}
                    {% if tag contains base_url %}
                        {% for tag in product.tags %}
                          {% if tag contains "COLOUR" %}
                            {% assign colour = tag | split: "_" | last %}
                          {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for tag in product.tags %}
                          {% if tag contains "SIZE" %}
                            {% assign size = tag | split: "_" | last %}
                          {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% if first_colour == colour and first_size == size%}{% continue %}{% endif %}
                        <div class="variant-div">
                          <a class="collec-variant" href="{{product.url}}"><img style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" src="{{ product.featured_media | img_url:'30x30' }}"></a>
                          <span class="tooltiptext">{{ colour }}</span>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
              {% endpaginate %}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Don't paginate through a huge number of products in Liquid

The 1000-item limit is a hard limit imposed by Shopify, for what I imagine are completely reasonable server-load reasons.  Whatever code you're writing has to be run on Shopify's servers when the page is generated for a user.  Remember also that Liquid is a templating language, *not* a programming language, and so is optimized for templating functions and not for complex object manipulation!

The time required for Shopify to compile and send the page to the client's browser can also be severely affected by huge loops with costly server operations, significantly increasing the lag between when a user requests your page and when Shopify is able to start transmitting the page content. I have seen pages that have tried to do variations of what you're looking to do and have watched as the TTFB (time-to-first-byte) grow to 5 seconds... 10 seconds... even as high as 20+ seconds in extreme cases.  Your visitors will quickly decide that their time is better spent elsewhere as the loading time increases!

### Step 2: Step back and look for ways to defer grabbing the additional content

'Defer' in this case means breaking up your code & logic in such a way that you can start fetching information without interrupting the initial compilation, transmission and rendering of the page.

Here's a rough overview of how I might approach this. Of course, you know your specific circumstances a lot better than a random stranger on the internet, so this is presented as a guide for inspiration and not as something carved in stone.

- Javascript will allow us to fetch data from a different URL in an 'asynchronous' (non-blocking) way and generate HTML that we can insert later, so let's move as much as we can to Javascript.
- Remove the entire `<div id="prod-var" class="prod-variants">` component from the Liquid code and replace it with a placeholder. We will need to be able to identify the placeholder and which product it belongs to, so let's make it something like `<div class="prod-var loading" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}">` *(Note: If there is any chance that there can be more than one `prod-var` element on the page we should be using classes, not IDs. Per HTML spec, an ID is expected to be 100% absolutely unique on any given page)*
- Optionally, in our CSS file, we can make some styles for `.prod-var.loading` so that we show a nice loading animation or something while we fetch the data.
- Now let's make our JS file. We will want the code to execute after the initial paint of the page so that our customers can see all of our fantastic products as soon as possible, so let's load it with the `defer` attribute so that it won't run until after all of the HTML content has loaded: `<script src="{{ 'script-filename.js' | asset_url }}" defer></script>`

In our JS file, we know that we want to perform the following steps:

1. Fetch a lot of product data
2. Keep fetching product data until we run out
3. Loop through all the products on the page
4. For each product, generate our HTML for the `prod-var` elements
5. Append the HTML to the appropriate element and remove the `loading` class

Sketching out a rough idea for our JS file, we might have something that looks similar to this:

```
function populateAllProdVars(){
  // I set this up using promise-chaining notation, but you can certainly use async/await, traditional callbacks, or anything else you are comfortable with
  fetchMyProducts()
    .then(generateProdVarHTML)
    .catch(/* SOME ERROR HANDLING FUNCTION */)
}

fetchMyProducts(productListSoFar, page){
  productListSoFar = productListSoFar || []; // Setting [] as a default
  page = page || 1; // Setting page 1 as a default

  return fetch('/collections/all/products.json?page=' + page)
           .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
           .then(function(collectionJSON){
             // Recursively keep going until we run out of products
             if(collectionJSON.products.length){
               productListSoFar = productListSoFar.concat(collectionJSON.products);
               return fetchMyProducts(productListSoFar, page+1);
             }
             else {
               // No more products, time to move on to the next step
               return productListSoFar;
             }
           }
}

function generateProdVarHTML(productList){
  var prodVarElements = document.querySelectorAll('.prod-var.loading');
  for(var i=0; i<prodVarElements.length; i++){
    var element = prodVarElements[e];
    var productId = element.dataset.productId;
    var relatedProducts = productList.filter(/* SOME FILTER FUNCTION */);
    var prodVarHTML = /* SOME FUNCTION TO TURN ARRAY OF RELATED PRODUCTS INTO RELEVANT HTML */
    element.innerHTML = prodVarHTML;
    element.classList.remove('loading');
  }
}

populateAllProdVars();
```

There are plenty of places where this could be improved further, especially if you can find all the related products through a more specific collection.  You might also want to consider making a custom collection view that only prints the relevant data rather than fetch the entire prodct.json contents and thus save some bandwidth for your customers and simplify the objects that the user's device needs to hold in memory (which can benefit shoppers on mobile devices).  I used the default pagination limit, but you can adjust that by adding a `&limit=100` (or whatever value you find works best) to the end of the collections/all/products URL.

Hopefully this gets you closer to what you need while also helping your site's performance overall.